# Touch script Windows 7 input

Tags: touch, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity Windows app which use Touch script library to recognize Windows 7 touches in 3D models. I have been working in Unity 4.3 up to now and everything has been working fine.

Now I want to upgrade to Unity 5. When I do that still the 3D model touches are working fine. But when I have the Windows 7 touch input enabled in Touch script, the rest of the app's single touches don't work anymore, e.g. HTML links/buttons (shown through coherent UI) or GUI button clicks etc..

Any ideas on how to fix this is really appreciated.